# How to replace \\n by \n in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a `string test="first \\n middle \\n last"`

Now I want to replace all `"\\n"` by `"\n"`

I've tried `test.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\\n")` and `test.replaceAll("\\n", "\n")` but they don't work
Anyone has a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: sr, you reply so quick, I've edited my question

Comment: Why? How did you get the string? Why did it have \\n in the first place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this code:

```
String test="first \\n middle \\n last";
System.out.println("Output: " + test.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n"));
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Output: first 
 middle 
 last
```

`"\\\\"` + `"n"` for backslash `"\\"` and `"n"` in original string is being replaced by `"\n"`