# How to replace "\\n" character to "\n" in a String?

Tags: java

I have a string as follows,

```
String test = "abc\\ndef";
```

I want replace "\\n" characters to "\n" character. I tried as follows but it doesnt work as expected.

```
test.replace("\\\\n","\\n")
```

What am I doing wrong here? Finally test variable should be "abc\ndef" please note that \n is not for new line, it is plane characters.

Note: this is not a duplicate of  [How to replace \\n by \n in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010559/how-to-replace-n-by-n-in-java) , it generates a new line character, but here I want characters "\n" not new line. **So please reconsider before down voting**.

Comment: So in your final string, do you want a new-line character, or a single backslash followed by `n`? Because `String test = "abc\\ndef";` **already has** a single backslash followed by `n`.

Comment: your test string has already the desired value.. no need to replace something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace \\n by \n in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010559/how-to-replace-n-by-n-in-java)

Comment: You have such a string how? Why? You'd have to work awfully hard to get it. Please explain. XY problem here.

Comment: @user207421 this string is I got from a RSA public key (when trying to put public key to json)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace \\n by \n in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010559/how-to-replace-n-by-n-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
test.replace("\\\n","\n");
```

Comment: Yes I have, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Check the question again @SudhirOjha. *Finally test variable should be "abc\ndef" please note that \n is **not** for new line, it is plane characters.*